# Remove empty string values and ignore casing in C# List when using Distinct() method

Tags: c#, linq

I have managed to remove most of the duplicate values in my list, but I still have lower-case duplicates, and empty string values in my list that I want to remove.

CategoriesList yield returns about 1000 records; `noDuplicateCategories` reduces this number to 20 removing most of the duplicates:

```
var CSVCategories = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1)
                            let columns = line.Split(',')
                            select new Category
                            {
                                Name = columns[9]
                            };

            var CategoriesList = CSVCategories.ToList();

            var noDuplicateCategories = CategoriesList.Distinct(new CategoryComparer()).ToList();
```

This is my object class overridden methods for the Equalitycomparer Interface:

```
class CategoryComparer : IEqualityComparer<Category>
{
    // Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal.
    public bool Equals(Category x, Category y)
    {

        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null ) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name, true) == 0;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(Category category)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(category, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int hashCategoryName = category.Name == null ? 0 : category.Name.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the Code field.
        int hashCategoryCode = category.Name.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product.
        return hashCategoryName;
    }

}
```

What do I need to change here to remove empty string values and also ignore casing?

My data:
[image]

Comment: You should remove empty strings with a `where` clause, not with a comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why deal with `Category` object if all you need to be unique is name. You can prepare names before converting them to categories:

```
var categories = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1)
           .Select(l => l.Split(new [] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
           .Where(parts => parts.Length >= 10)
           .Select(parts => parts[9].Trim())
           .Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
           .Select(s => new Category { Name = s });
```

Of course if you are pretty sure that data in your file is reliable - no empty lines, every line has at least 10 parts, and each part does not have whitespace around, then you can simplify query to

```
var categories = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1)
           .Select(l => l.Split(',')[9])
           .Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
           .Select(s => new Category { Name = s });
```

NOTE: Use `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` to avoid dumping all file content into in-memory array.

Comment: Thank you Sergey. How do I become better at LINQ? Are there any free online challenges to practice at querying using LINQ? Or do you think it is best to learn it when developing?

Comment: @aladdin786 i would start with practicing LINQ with LinqPad (there is hands-on LINQ samples included) and watching some tutorials like Pluralsight. Then practice, practice :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll check out LinqPad. Although I don't have the budget to use Pluralsight.

Comment: @aladdin786 checkout channel 9 from microsoft, there is lot of videos [tagget with linq](https://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/linq)

Comment: One more question regarding the answer: the 'StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase' completely ignores casing, but I want to still have items returned that have the first letter as being capital. Is this a good way to do it:  .Select(s => new Category { Name = s.First().ToString().ToUpper() + s.Substring(1) }); ?

Comment: @aladdin786 I would go with `Char.ToUpper(str[0]) + str.Substring(1)` but your solution also will work